# Why is $A \times \bigcup \mathscr{B} = \bigcup\{ A \times Z \mid Z \in \mathscr{B} \}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen this answer given as a solution:

> **Solution.** Take $\langle x, y \rangle \in A \times \bigcup \mathscr{B}$. So $y \in \bigcup \mathscr{B}$, and thus there exists some $X \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $y \in X$. Hence $\langle x, y \rangle \in A \times X$, and thus $\langle x,y \rangle \in \bigcup \{A \times X \mid X \in \mathscr{B}\}$. Conversely, if $\langle x, y \rangle \in A \times X$ for some $X \in \mathscr{B}$, then $y \in \bigcup \mathscr{B}$, and so $\langle x, y \rangle \in A \times \bigcup \mathscr{B}$.

But I do not understand why this shows that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in the generalised union of the cartesian product of $A$ and $X$, such that $X$ is in $\mathscr{B}$. Doesn't it just show that, if $\langle x,y \rangle \in A\times X$, then $\langle x, y \rangle$ is in $\{A \times  X \mid X \in \mathscr{B} \}$?

Comment: `\mathscr B` for $\mathscr B$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What does the $\bigcup$ notation mean in $\bigcup\{A\times Z | Z\in B\}$? I understand in the first instance, you use it to mean $\bigcup B \equiv \bigcup_{Z\in B} Z$. Is this correct? In that case, in the second instance, I don't see how it makes much sense, because the elements of $\bigcup\{A\times Z | Z\in B\}$ are tuples, not sets. Perhaps I am simply not familiar with this notation

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen: It's the same notation: $$\bigcup\{A\times Z\mid Z\in B\} = \bigcup_{X\in\{A\times Z\mid Z \in B\}} X = \bigcup_{Z\in B} A\times Z $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right I guess I brain farted, I was just about to delete my comment :P Thanks

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen $\cup A$ is the set determined by $x\in A\iff x\in a$ for some $a\in A$. We have $\cup A=\bigcup_{a\in A}a$

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen $A \cup B$ is really a special notation for $\cup \{A,B\}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times X\tag1$$ is not the same thing as $$\langle x,y\rangle\in\{A\times X\mid X\in\mathscr B\}\tag2$$
as you seem to think. Note e.g. that the elements of $\{A\times X\mid X\in\mathscr B\}$ are sets of the form $A\times X$ and not ordered pairs like $\langle x,y\rangle$.

However if $X\in\mathscr B$ then (1) allows you to conclude that $\langle x,y\rangle\in\bigcup\{A\times X\mid X\in\mathscr B\}$.

This because the set $\bigcup Z$ is by definition the set characterized by: $$u\in\bigcup Z\iff u\in z\text{ for some }z\in Z$$

---

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times\bigcup\mathscr B$
- $x\in A\wedge y\in\bigcup\mathscr B$
- $x\in A\wedge y\in X$ for some $X\in\mathscr B$
- $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times X$ for some $X\in\mathscr B$
- $\langle x,y\rangle\in D$ for some $D\in\{A\times X\mid X\in\mathscr B\}$
- $\langle x,y\rangle\in\bigcup\{A\times X\mid X\in\mathscr B\}$

Comment: Thank you both, this has (I think) cleared it up. Just to be clear, the issue is that I've just confused 'A x B' with {A x B}, by ignoring the curly brackets, hence the latter is a set of set of ordered pairs, whereas the former is just a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: I have not the impression that you confused $A\times B$ and $\{A\times B\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}$ is a **collection of sets** $A\times X$ so $\langle x,y\rangle\notin\{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}$ because $\langle x,y\rangle$ is an element of some element of the collection but not an element of the collection.

$$A\times X\in\{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}\land\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times X\implies \langle x,y\rangle\notin \{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}$$

But when you apply the union operator you have a **union of sets** of the kind $A\times X$ so

$$A\times X\subset\bigcup\{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}\implies\langle x,y\rangle\in\bigcup \{A\times X|X\in\mathscr B\}$$